# How does cron handle the "day" field?

Tags: cron

I'm trying to create a dynamic task scheduler with [cron syntax](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?crontab%205).

How does cron handle days that overflow the number of days in the month? For example, now it's February with 29 days. How would cron handle the day expressions `31` or `*/2`?

If `*/2` is expanded to `1,3,5..29,31` I could see that 31 is dropped. But that wouldn't work so well if day is just `31`. Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe cron just ignores it if it doesn't match.  The way the man page is written says that it matches if either the day of month match or the day of week matches.  Some implementations ([cronie](https://fedorahosted.org/cronie/) for instance) just evaluate */2 in DoM to 1,3,5,7..,31, so it must ignore 31 in February.

Comment: So `* * 31 * *` would only run on 7 months/year?

Answer (score 1):

It will just ignore it, because it uses just a simple match. You are probably trying to achieve "run this every last day of a month". Something like this should work (found it [here](http://tutorialpedia.org/tutorials/How+to+set+a+cron+job+to+run+at+the+end+of+the+month.html)):

```
59 23 * * * [ `date -d tomorrow +%d` -eq '01' ] && <your script>
```

Or make that cron to run every day, but let it run this .sh script:

```
TODAY=`date +%d`
TOMORROW=`date +%d -d "1 day"`

# If tomorrow date is less than today, we are at the end of the month
if  [  $TOMORROW  -lt  $TODAY  ];  then
  # This is the last day of the month, so you can do your stuff here...run other script...
fi
```

Comment: So `* * 31 * *` would only run on 7 months/year?

Comment: Yes, only on months with 31 days.